# NSKeyValueChangeKey ambiguous reference to member subscript

Tags: swift3, xcode8

when i am convert from swift 2 to swift 3
the error which am facing is **"ambiguous reference to member subscript"**

Below is my code :

```
class KeyValueChange {

    fileprivate let change: [String : AnyObject]

    init(change: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.change = change
    }

    var kind: NSKeyValueChange? {
        guard let value = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.kindKey] as? NSNumber else {
            return nil
        }

        return NSKeyValueChange(rawValue: value.uintValue)
    }

    var indexSet: IndexSet? {
        return change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.indexesKey] as? IndexSet
    }

    var new: AnyObject? {
        return change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]
    }

}
```

Please elaborate it properly because in many place getting same error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3, KVO method `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` passes `[NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?` for `change` parameter. If you want to use your `KeyValueChange` class with it, you'd better adapt to the change:

```
class KeyValueChange {

    private let change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]

    init(change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]) {
        self.change = change
    }

    var kind: NSKeyValueChange? {

        guard let value = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.kindKey] as? NSNumber else {
            return nil
        }

        return NSKeyValueChange(rawValue: value.uintValue)
    }

    var indexSet: IndexSet? {
        return change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.indexesKey] as? IndexSet
    }

    var new: Any? {
        return change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]
    }

}
```